# vagrant - shutting down host machine

Tags: vagrant, windows-10, ubuntu-14.04

I am pretty new to vagrant. I have installed an ubuntu 14.04 trusty box on my vagrant and will use it for my web development environment. I want to know which is the best way to disable/close/shutdown a vagrant box so that data in it remain safe in the next session? I mean when I want to shutdown my laptop (in windows 10, my host machine os is win10) there is a message telling me that virtualbox interface is open. so if I close the process then I cant access vagrant box anymore. I want a good way to close vagrant and run it in my next working session.

I read about vagrant halt before host shutdown and using vagrant up in next session but it takes too long to run a vagrant up.

**summary : I WANT A WAY TO DO THIS:

1- close a vagrant box without a data loss in it;

2- shutdown my laptop without seeing the message that tells virtualbox interface is open.

3- run vagrant box and access it with putty as fast as possible when I start working again.

is there a way to do this?**

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know which is the best way to disable/close/shutdown a vagrant box so that data in it remain safe in the next session

I would not necessarily to recommend `vagrant halt` which will completely stop your VM and will need to start up after you restart your host.

You can run `vagrant suspend` which will hold your data and you will retrieve your instance in the same state as it was before on your next startup

You can read more about the [differences between halt and suspend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42551494/4296747)

Comment: is it something like hibernate in windows? then virtual box interface message wont show up? if so, then what command is used to restore last session?

Comment: yes its exactly like hibernate in windows - you restore the session by running `vagrant up` (same as if vagrant was halted, in the case of suspend, vagrant will detect it was suspended and will restore)