# vagrant command - vagrant init vs add

Tags: vagrant

I am new to Vagrant. I have read through Vagrant documentation, but I am still confused with both commands - vagrant add and vagrant init. I only know how vagrant init will initialize a VM instance but I'm not sure with vagrant add. Both look like the same for me. What's the actual difference between these 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `vagrant add` command - I assume your refer to `vagrant box add`.

You can also read https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657143/4296747 where I try to describe initial steps from vagrant.

to answer your question:

- `vagrant box add` add a box into the box repository, it download a vagrant box file from internet and copy the files under your `$HOME/.vagrant.d` and pre-configure the box so it can be used when you will run a VM; it does not create any VM you can use.
- `vagrant init` is just a basic script that will create a skeleton `Vagrantfile`. You run this command if you dont have any Vagrantfile to work with and you are not sure how to write one.

Note that if you have your own `Vagrantfile` you dont need the `vagrant init` and when running `vagrant up` vagrant automatically downloads the box for you so as a beginner you can skip `vagrant box add`